# Which PHP Framework to use with Facebook HipHop in mind

Tags: php, frameworks, hiphop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Facebook's hiphop with frameworks like Zend Framework, cakephp, symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190270/can-i-use-facebooks-hiphop-with-frameworks-like-zend-framework-cakephp-symfony)

I am developing a social platform that has the potential to have millions of users, so I want to develop it in PHP using what ever framework is going to work best with Facebook's HipHop. Do popular php frameworks like (ZF, CakePHP, symfony) have compatibility with HipHop? If not, which parts of this frameworks are not usable?

Comment: This has already been discussed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623975/php-mvc-orm-frameworks-that-are-hyper-php-hiphop-ready http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190270/can-i-use-facebooks-hiphop-with-frameworks-like-zend-framework-cakephp-symphon

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't even started developing your site yet, it seems a little bit silly to start worrying about how it's going to work when there are millions of users. There is no perfect framework that works well with a product that's just and idea, and HipHop isn't universally well-suited for all sites (even the [creator of PHP](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/rasmus-lerdorf-php-hiphop-facebook.php) says so).

With that said, I'd focus on building a site that works. Once tens of people start using it, then worry about hundreds. From there, thousands. Don't solve far-off problems before you've solved the glaring ones.

With that said, if you're still looking for a framework, [another SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190270/can-i-use-facebooks-hiphop-with-frameworks-like-zend-framework-cakephp-symphon) posted a similar question.

Comment: I dont think its silly at all. The more prepared you are to handle millions of users the less of a headache it is when you do get bombarded and need to scramble to find a solution.

Comment: For example you can start not using eval in your code, so it becomes an easy transition in hiphop later down the line.

Comment: Failure to plan is a plan to fail. What happens when you make your site as simple as possible and then it makes headlines in your local newspaper. Your site will get bombarded with 1000's of users when you only planned for 100's of them.